Is it ever possible that wages can inversely related to Labor Supply? If so does it have a name?
This might come off as an odd question but are there any frameworks that associate a reduction in wages with an increase in labor supply?
A scenario would be the following:

Suppose a worker receives a wage cut and since this worker has bills to pay they need to do more overtime.

An example of this labor supply curve would be:

Is there a name for this phenomenon?

Backward bending supply curve of labour?

@HerrK. More like an S shaped labor supply curve.

The same Wikipedia article has a section on that too.
